# Is it possible, to re-convert an .exe to python3-Script again?

Tags: python-3.x, exe

I'm writing a program with a Login-Window at the beginning.
Since this program is only for my personal use, there is only
one password set, which is implemented in the code. I built an .exe
via pyinstaller and its not possible to read out information out of the
.exe-file. Now i would like to know, if it's possible to re-convert
the .exe into the python3-script to read out the password, or if there is any other way to get information about the script using the .exe-file.

Comment: http://evolvedmicrobe.com/blogs/?p=429 Apparently 'pyinstxtractor.py' is a tool that allows decompilation of pyinstaller binaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried yet, but I found in some blog that the following command works.

```
python pyinstxtractor.py file_to_decompile
```